# Список стандартных приложений Windows

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

Как можно получить список стандартных приложений Windows и занести их в comboBox и запускать, нажав на Button? Возможно,есть какие-то варианты, не прописывая от руки каждое приложение.

Comment: `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Accessories` вы имели ввиду программы из **Пуск -> Все программы -> Стандартные**? Сканируем все файлы ярлыков и выводим списком.

Comment: Что тут подразумевается под "стандартными приложениями"?

Comment: Блокнот, Media Player  и тд